# Find repeated pattern in text with "Re" Python

Tags: python, regex

Would anybody kindly help me in the following example (If I use `re.DOTALL`, it reads until end of the file):

```
import re

text = "Found to A from:\n\t-B\n\t-C\nFound to K from:\n\t-B\n\t-D\n\t-E\nFound to A from:\n\t-D\nMax time: 20s"

names = ['A', 'K']
for name in names:
    print name
    print re.findall("Found to {0} from:\n\t\-(.+)".format(name), text)
```

TEXT is like :

[image]

OUTPUT:

```
A

['B', 'D']

K

['B']
```

Desired OUTPUT:

```
A

['B', 'C', 'D']

K

['B', 'D', 'E']
```

Comment: Can you a.) Provide more realistic input strings and b.) format your question correctly (the curly braces are for code) ?

Comment: Thanks @Jan, Please check it now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

And here is another approach (Python 2.7x):

```
import re
text = 'Found to A from:\n\t-B\n\t-C\nFound to K from:\n\t-B\n\t-D\n\t-E\nFound to A from:\n\t-D\nMax time: 20s'
for name in ['A', 'K']:
    print name
    print [ n for i in re.findall('(?:Found to ' + name + ' from:)(?:\\n\\t-([A-Z]))(?:\\n\\t-([A-Z]))?(?:\\n\\t-([A-Z]))?', text) for n in i if n ]
```

Output:

```
A
['B', 'C', 'D']
K
['B', 'D', 'E']
```

**UPDATE** In case you don't know how many (?:\n\t-([A-Z])), I suggest the following approach:

```
import re
text = 'Found to A from:\n\t-B\n\t-C\n\t-G\nFound to K from:\n\t-B\n\t-D\n\t-E\nFound to A from:\n\t-D\nMax time: 20s'
for name in ['A', 'K']:
    print name
    groups = re.findall('(?:Found to ' + name + ' from:)((?:\\n\\s*-(?:[A-Z]))+)', text)
    print reduce(lambda i,j: i + j, map(lambda x: re.findall('\n\s*-([A-Z])', x), groups))
```

Output:

```
A
['B', 'C', 'G', 'D']
K
['B', 'D', 'E']
```

Comment: Hi @ccf, very nice, thanks, just one point. I don't know how many (?:\\n\\t-([A-Z])) there is in my text. Is it possible to change it to something like (?:\\n\\t-([A-Z]))+

Comment: @Mansour:  (?:\\n\\t-([A-Z]))+ is good for same pattern repeats, like \n\t-B\n\t-B\n\t-B\n\t-B, and does not apply to your situation.

Comment: Do you know how I can solve it because the number of items is not fixed?

Comment: Please try the updated implementation to see if it can address your concerns.

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot @ccf

Answer (score 2):

When I was typing this answer I was trying to answer your original question where you had a file with specific content to parse. I think my answer still applies. If you have a string instead, change

```
for line in f:
```

to

```
for line in f.splitlines():
```

and pass the string instead of the file object to `keys_and_values`.

Original answer:

In all honesty I think this looks like a task where the heavy lifting should be done by a generator, with some help from regular expressions.

```
import re
from collections import OrderedDict

def keys_and_values(f):
    # discard any headers
    target = '^\s*Found to [A-Z] from:\s*$'
    for line in f:
        if re.match(target, line.strip()):
            break

    # yield (key, value) tuples
    key = line.strip()[9]
    for line in f:
        line = line.strip()
        if re.match(target, line):
            key = line[9]
        elif line:
            yield (key, line)

result = OrderedDict()
with open('testfile.txt') as f:
    for k,v in keys_and_values(f):
        result.setdefault(k, []).append(v)

for k in result:
    print('{}\n{}\n'.format(k, result[k]))
```

Demo:

```
$ cat testfile.txt 
some
useless
header
lines

Found to A from:

B

C

Found to K from:

B

D

E

Found to A from:

D
$ python parsefile.py
A
['B', 'C', 'D']

K
['B', 'D', 'E']
```

Comment: Thanks @timegeb, I wanted to do it by Regex, not parsing lines of code. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @Mansour no problem. I still think that this is not a good task to solve by regex alone. The generator is easier to maintain and adjust for any eventualities. It will also work for files that are too large to read at once, where the regex solution will fail. It is your choice, of course.

Comment: Thanks @timegeb!! Can I kindly ask why it should not be solved by regex alone ? You mean because of time complexity ? Or because we don't know how many dashed items we have in each section ?

Comment: @Mansour Well, I already named a few reasons. The main ones are that a) you have to assume less about your input file. The more chaotic it can be the more complicated and unreadable the regex will become and b) the generator uses minimal memory, you don't have to read in the file at once.

Comment: I got your points now @timgeb. As far as my files are small, regex is fine for them, but I will consider your clues in future. Thanks again :-)

Answer (score 0):

Not generic but works in your case and is simple and is using findAll like you mentioned.

```
import re

text = "Found to A from:\n\t-B\n\t-C\nFound to K from:\n\t-B\n\t-D\n\t-E\nFound to A from:\n\t-D\n"

names = ['A', 'K']
for name in names:
    print name
    test = re.findall("Found to {0} from:\n\t-([A-Z])(\n\t)?-?([A-Z])?(\n\t)?-?([A-Z])?".format(name), text)
    # normalize it
    prettyList = []
    for (a,b,c,d,e) in test:
        prettyList.append(a)
        prettyList.append(c)
        prettyList.append(e)
    print [x for x in prettyList if x]
```

The output

```
A
['B', 'C', 'D']
K
['B', 'D', 'E']
```

I know there are lot of cases with 3 Elements and so on you have to add the additional matching.